# Prove that $p$ divides $(p-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k-1}x^k/k $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime such that $p\mid x^3-1$ but $p\not\mid x-1$. Prove that $$p \mid (p-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k} $$

This is my work,

**Lemma** if $p$ is prime then $$k^{-1}\equiv (-1)^{k-1}{p \choose k}/p\pmod p$$

Now note that $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k}\equiv \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}x^k{p \choose k}/p\equiv\frac{1}{p}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}x^k{p \choose k}\pmod p$$

And we know that $$(x+1)^p=\sum_{k=0}^{p}x^k{p \choose k}=1+x^p+\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}x^k{p \choose k}$$
Hence $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}x^k{p \choose k}\equiv 0\pmod p.$$

Also we know $(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod p$, so $$(p-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k}\equiv -\frac{1}{p}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}x^k{p \choose k}\pmod p$$

so we need to prove this last guy is divisible by $p$, or equivalently $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}x^k{p \choose k}\equiv 0\pmod{p^2}$$

Comment: Ok I realize that I made a mistake, my answer is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note first that because of $p|(x^3-1)$ and $p\not | (x-1)$ we have $x^3=1$, $x\ne1$  and  and $x^2+x+1=0$ modulo $p$. Besides there are only two values $a,b\in \mathbb F_p$ satisfying the equation $x^2+x+1=0$ and we have $a+b=-1$ and $ab=1$.

Further the only involved primes are those of the form $3n+1$ because if $p=3n+2$ then (Fermat's little theorem) $x^{3n+1}=x(x^3)^n=x=1$ modulo $p$. Moreover the factor  $(p-1)!$ is only the factor $-1$ modulo $p$ (Wilson's theorem) therefore in
$$p \mid (p-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k}\iff(p-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k}\equiv0\pmod p$$ we can consider just $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k}\equiv0\pmod p$$ for the only values $a,b$ of $x$ and $p$ a prime of the form $3n+1$.
$$*****$$
So we want to prove for $x=a$ and $x=b=\dfrac1a$ and the primes $p$ with the form $p\equiv1\pmod3$  $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k}\equiv0\pmod p$$ We have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{a^k}{k}=\left(a-\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^3}{3}\right)-a^3\left(\frac a4-\frac{a^2}{5}+\frac{a^3}{6}\right)+a^6\left(\frac a7-\frac{a^2}{8}+\frac{a^3}{9}\right)\cdots -a^{3(n-1)}\left(\frac {a}{p-3}-\frac{a^2}{p-2}+\frac{a^3}{p-1}\right)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{a^k}{k}=\left(\frac a1+\frac{a+1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)-\left(\frac a4+\frac{a+1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}\right)+\left(\frac a7+\frac{a+1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}\right)\cdots -\left(\frac {a}{p-3}+\frac{a+1}{p-2}+\frac{1}{p-1}\right)$$
This gives for some $A,B,C,D$ in $\mathbb F_p$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{a^k}{k}=Aa+B$$ if $Aa+B=C\iff Aa+D=0$. But we also have  $$\dfrac Aa+D=0$$ therefore $$A\left(a-\frac 1a\right)=0$$ from which $A=0$ and $D=0$ modulo $p$. We are done.

Comment: I like this mostly, but (a) what's the proof for the existence/uniqueness of the residues $a,b$ and (b) how do we rule out $n^2+n+1$ having no factors of $6k-1$? It's simple to show that $p = 6k+1$ and $n = 6m+1$, but that doesn't automatically rule out the possibility that $n = (6i-1)(6j-1)$. Brute force computation shows that it doesn't happen, but I think it's necessary for the proof, as having some $6i-1 \mid n^2+n+1$ would cause major issues.

Comment: To prove that $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$ just noe that $x^3\equiv 1\pmod p$ and also $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$. If $3\nmid p-1$, then $x\equiv 1\pmod p$ which contradicts the conditions of the problem.

Comment: @Eric Snyder: When the prime $p$ is fixed, the equation $x^2+x+1=0$ **over the field $\mathbb F_p$** has only two roots we have noted $a$ and $b$. The difficulty of this problem is just because the $x$ goes only for two values and for the numerical calculations to do if you don't use what I did. Another difficulty is if you don't remark that the primes involved are just of the form $3n+1$ (for having an exact number of trinomes analogues) Sorry for bad English.

Comment: @Piquito Thanks. I also realized after posting that if we just treat this as a quadratic with two roots, they have to fit $a+b = -1$ and $ab = 1$, which you can also do in modular arithmetic. As an interesting consequence, it's also true that $a^2 \equiv b \pmod p$ and $b^2 = a\pmod p$.

Comment: @richrow That's true for $p$, of course, but don't we also need to show that if $p \mid n^2 + n+1$, then $p \equiv 1 \pmod 6$, as well? That is, that $n^2 + n + 1$ has no factors of the form $6k - 1$?

Comment: @EricSnyder This follows from what I have already written. If $n^2+n+1$ divisible by $p$, then $n^3\equiv 1\pmod p$ and $n\not\equiv 1\pmod p$ unless $p=3$.

Comment: Further question: how does the end of the proof actually work? I understand how we get the $Aa+B \equiv C, Aa+D \equiv 0$, sort of handwaving "these have to exist." But I can't see whence the rest appears. $Aa +D \equiv 0$ doesn't imply $A/a + D \equiv 0$, but instead implies $-A/(a+1) \equiv D$. And don't we actually need to prove that $Aa+B \equiv 0$, that is, the actual sum is divisible by $p$?

Comment: @Eric Snyder: Values $A,B,C,D$ are constants modulo $p$ for a $p$ fixed. Its are the same "for all $x$". But the only possible values of $x$ are $a$ and $\dfrac1a$ which is equal to $−(1+a)$

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need now to prove that $(x+1)^p-x^p-1$ is divisible by $p^2$ (why?). Here is a sketch of the proof:

1. Prove that $3\mid p-1$ (you have an element of order 3 in $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$).
2. Prove that polynomial $(t+1)^n-t^n-1$ is divisible by $(t^2+t+1)^2$ when $6\mid n-1$ (just take the derivative and check that the complex roots of $x^2+x+1$ are also roots of the derivative). Thus, for $n\equiv 1\pmod 6$ we have the identity
   $$
   (t+1)^{n}-t^n-1=(t^2+t+1)^2q(t),
   $$
   where $q(t)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients.
3. Prove that $(x+1)^p-x^p-1$ is divisible by $p^2$.